# Big latency on Go channel send / receive? (PProf tracing)

Tags: go, channel, producer-consumer, goroutine, pprof

I was Using PProf to analyze tracing for a data pipeline with producer and consumer. I'm not sure how I should read this, but from the scheduler latency profile, `chanrecv` and `chansend` accounts for a decent portion of my total run time.

I find it hard to believe, so does this suggest go channel send/receive taking that long, or this only referring t producer lagging behind that leads to `chanrecv` blocking. And potentially how I can make this more efficient?

Sample code:

```
func consume(in chan User) {
    out := make(chan UserDetail)
    go func() {
        for user := range in {
            if userDetail, err := getUserDetails(user); err == nil {
                out <- userDetail
            }
        }
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}

func produce() {
    out := make(chan User)
    go func() {
        // could be issuing a paginated api call to get users list
        for user := range users {
            out <- user
        }
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}


func main() {
    userChan := produce() // get all users
    userDetailChannels := []chan User

    // fanout to 8 workers
    for workerIndex := 0; workerIndex < 8; workerIndex++ {
        userDetailChannels = append(userDetailChannels, consume(userChan))
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The easiest first step is setting the channel buffer size to some number > 0.

Comment: As the code you _showed_ doesn't do anything else than send and receive this is expected. If you need help you must provide a reproducable example.

Comment: Voting to close as we can't reproduce the problem from the details shown

Comment: @HymnsForDisco thank you! it does cut the latency in half but still curious if the `chanrecv` is referring to consumer waiting for producer or it's just the channel receive would take that long in go